# React.js, implementing timer, getting weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple timer with React, where start button starts the timer, and stop button pauses it. However this gives some unexpected behavior.

First click on start, the timer changes to 1 and pauses, on second click it oscillates between 1 and 2. Unable to understand why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0)
  let t;
  function startTime(){
    t = setInterval(()=>{
      setTime(time+1);
    },1000)
  }
  function stopTime(){
    clearInterval(t);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{time}</h1>
      <button onClick={startTime}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={stopTime}>Stop</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `setInterval` is an interesting challenge to implement in hooks. I'd read https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: Very much! Thanks for this resource!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did, on first click you create a function in memory that will call `setTime(0+1)` for ever, as 0 is the value of `time` when you registered that function in memory. To have the updated `time`, you would wanna pass a function to `setTime`.

Also, to memoize the interval reference, you should be using a React `ref`, as a normal variable will come to its  initial value at each render. Here is a working example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wilbur-g6k3kp?file=/src/App.js) and the code below:

```js
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0)
  const timerRef = useRef();
  function startTime(){
    timerRef.current = setInterval(()=>{
      setTime(time =>time+1);
    },1000)
  }
  function stopTime(){
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{time}</h1>
      <button onClick={startTime}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={stopTime}>Stop</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Got the point. Any tips on how to clear this intervals?

Comment: Glad I could help! Clearing ? Put the `time` to `0` you mean ? Because it's already clearing when you click on stop and call `stopTime` function.

Comment: Ah sorry, maybe my page didn't load properly. Gotta study useRef! Thanks again!

Comment: Javascript intervals and timeouts are unreliable as they can be throttled, it's safer to save the current date when a user clicks start, update the component at a specific interval and subtract that value from the current date. Your ref will also not trigger an update, thus the new value will never be visible. And you have a memory leak when the component is removed because you never clear the interval. This implementation requires a `useEffect`.